# C# System.InvalidOperationException has been thrown: Cannot start process because a file name has not been provided

Tags: c#

The command line "XVirus.Start();" is giving me "System.InvalidOperationException has been thrown: Cannot start process because a file name has not been provided.".
But before that happened, it started my program without any problems at all. The code is still the same before and after it happened. Here is my code if you need it.

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;

namespace FDVirusX
{
    class MainClass
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var XVirus = new Process();

        var driveList = DriveInfo.GetDrives();

        foreach (DriveInfo drive in driveList)
        {
            if (drive.DriveType == DriveType.Removable)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Scanning Flash Drive: " + drive.Name + drive.VolumeLabel);

                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1900);

                if (Directory.GetFiles(drive.ToString(), "*.lnk", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Length == 0)
                {
                    XVirus.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = drive.ToString();
                    XVirus.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
                    XVirus.StartInfo.Arguments = " /c title FDVirusX & cls & @echo off & echo There are no shortcut viruses in this Flash Drive.";
                    XVirus.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                    XVirus.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
                }
                else 
                {
                    XVirus.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = drive.ToString();
                    XVirus.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
                    XVirus.StartInfo.Arguments = "/c title FDVirusX & cls & attrib -s -h -r /s /d & echo Files restored. & del /f /s *.lnk & echo Shortcut files deleted.";
                    XVirus.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                    XVirus.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
                }
                if (!Directory.Exists(drive.ToString()))
                {
                    XVirus.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"C:/";
                    XVirus.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
                    XVirus.StartInfo.Arguments = "/c title FDVirusX & cls & @echo off & echo Flash Drive not found.";
                    XVirus.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                    XVirus.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
                }
            }
        }
        XVirus.Start(); // System.InvalidOperationException has been thrown: Cannot start process because a file name has not been provided.
        Console.WriteLine(XVirus.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd());
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
        Console.WriteLine("Closing Application...");
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
        XVirus.WaitForExit();
        XVirus.Close();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: What happens here if you don't have any removable drive ready?

Comment: By the way, what is the executable name that should be run by CMD.EXE. That title as first argument should be the exe name.

Comment: It will say "Flash drive not found"

Comment: I tested it again with my flash drive and everything worked fine again, but without the flash disk, it will not display the "Flash Drive not found." but it will give me the System.InvalidOperationException

Comment: Because if you don't have any removable drivre ready your code skips the foreach and leave the variable XVirus  empty of any info..... By the way, if you have more than one removable drivre your code works only on the last one

Comment: Last time i tested it without the Flash Drive, it worked perfectly fine though.

Answer (score 1):

Either this driveList is empty:

```
var driveList = DriveInfo.GetDrives();
```

Or none are removable:

```
   if (drive.DriveType == DriveType.Removable)
```

Some simple debugging will establish the problem.

Comment: It should say "Flash Drive not found.". I tested the code again with my flash drive and everything worked fine again. But the problem is the "Flash Drive not found." making the error.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check if you have any removable drive ready to be processed.
Initialize the XVirus variable only if the GetDrives method returns any removable drive.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // Be explicit and keep it initialized as null, so you could 
    // check it at the end of the loop if there are drives to process
    Process XVirus = null;

    // We are interested only in the removable drives. 
    // Linq is good choice here
    foreach (DriveInfo drive in DriveInfo.GetDrives()
                       .Where(x => x.DriveType == DriveType.Removable && 
                                   x.IsReady)
    {
         XVirus = new Process();

         ..... initialize the XVirus operating parameters ...

         // and remove this block because is not needed now 
         // if (!Directory.Exists(drive.ToString()))
         // {
         //     ...
         // }
    }

    // At the end if XVirus is still null we know that 
    // no removable drives  are available
    if(XVirus == null)
        MessageBox.Show("You don't have any removable drive ready")
    else
        ..... process the found drive ....
}
```

Also, if you want to process more than one drive then you should move the code that process the drive inside the foreach loop

Comment: I'm sorry but the line if(XVirus == null) still doesn't work if there is no Removable Drive.

Comment: I see, we need to add a check on IsReady

Comment: Keep in mind that this kind of operations could always fail. A robust error trapping with a try/catch should be put around this code because you cannot deny to your user the ability to manually remove the drive while you are working on it

Answer (score 1):

It seems like i don't need the line

```
                    if (!Directory.Exists(drive.ToString()))
                {
                    XVirus.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"C:/";
                    XVirus.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
                    XVirus.StartInfo.Arguments = "/c title FDVirusX & cls & @echo off & echo Flash Drive not found.";
                    XVirus.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                    XVirus.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
                }
```

at all. Thank you everyone for trying to help me solve the problem of my code.